# If you covered Canada with 1 mole's worth of golf balls, how thick would the layer of golf balls be?

Tags: arithmetic, area, estimation

I know moles are a chemistry thing, but only really the quantity matters in this question.

Canada, without counting the water, has an area of $9,093,507 \text{ km}^2$. A golf ball (pretending it is square) has a width/height of $4.318 \times 10^{-5}$ km. If I covered Canada with 1 mole ($6.022 \times 10^{23}$) of golf balls, how thick would the pile of golf balls be?

Comment: See also: [a mole of moles](https://what-if.xkcd.com/4/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer will depend on how the golf balls are packed. A random packing of equally sized spheres has packing density $0.6400$, that is, it would occupy $64.00\%$ of the space that contains it (see [MathWorld: Sphere Packing](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePacking.html)). A hexagonal close packing, on the other hand, is far more efficient and has packing density $0.7405$. If there are $n$ many balls, each of volume $v$, packed together with density $\rho$, they will have a total volume that satisfies ${\rho}=\frac{nv}{V}$. If those packed balls are amassed up to an approximately level height $h$ on a surface with area $A$, then they will approximately form a prism (with an irregular base) of volume $V=hA$. It follows from elementary algebra that $h=\frac{nv}{\rho A}$. In your case, a random packing (hence, density $\rho=0.6400$) of $n=6.0\times10^{23}$ approximately spherical balls of diameter $4.3\,\mathrm{cm}$ (hence, volume $v=41\,\mathrm{cm}^3$) on a surface of area $9\times10^{6}\,\mathrm{km}^2$ will have height $4\times10^{3}\,\mathrm{km}$.

Comment: This estimate is consistent with the XKCD estimate for a mole (amount) of moles (animals) on the earth, where the packed objects have equal number and volume of the same order of magnitude ($75\, \mathrm{g}\cdot 1\,\mathrm{cm}^3/\mathrm{g}$ [moles are smaller than I realized!]), and they are spread out over an area $+2$ orders of magnitude greater in extent ($510\times10^6\,\mathrm{km}^2$, the surface area of the Earth). So we should expect in that case to have a height $\approx -2$ orders of magnitude less, as indeed we do ($80 \mathrm{km}$).

Comment: With that much height, you should take into account the fact that the Earth is not flat.  If we take the Earth to be a sphere of radius $R$, covering area $A$ of the surface to height $h$ produces a volume of $$A ((R+h)^3 - R^3))/(3R^2)= A(h + h^2/R + h^3/(3 R^2)$$

Comment: For completeness: A *cubic* packing, with an efficiency of $\frac{\pi}{6} \approx 0.5236$, would require a depth of 5332 km.  In contrast, a completely efficient packing (if balls can be deformed or melted while preserving their volume) would need only 2792 km.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Canada is big enough to force us to consider this.

Comment: It's not the area of the base, it's the height: $4 \times 10^3$ km is nearly $63\%$ of the radius of the Earth.